# Google Cast Remote Display Sometimes Loses Video or Audio

Tags: android, google-cast

My Android app uses the Remote Display API to cast video to the user's Cast-enabled device. Unfortunately, we have to use a proprietary video player, hence why I can't use the normal video API. This is sadly out of my control.

The app waits for the user to select a Display and launch a video. I would say that it works well approximately 50% of the time. Often, audio will cease to play while the video continues. Sometimes (but more rarely) the opposite happens- the Cast screen turns black while audio continues. And there is often audio and video skipping while the video plays, which isn't experienced when just viewing on the device.

I gather playing video over Remote Display isn't ideal, but I'd think audio and video should continue streaming throughout, especially since Remote Display was created for graphic-intensive games in-mind.

Also, the fact that audio stops when the activity is pushed into the background is a bit of a deal-breaker. Are there any plans to change this?

Here are some pieces of code that show how I'm creating the connection and starting video. Maybe I'm doing something dumb that causes it to perform poorly?

This code is called when the user selects a device from the MediaRouteChooserDialog:

```
@Override
public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
    selectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());

    Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity,
            ExampleMainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("cast", true);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mainActivity, 0, intent, 0);

    CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.NotificationSettings settings =
            new CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.NotificationSettings.Builder()
                    .setNotificationPendingIntent(notificationPendingIntent).build();

    CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.startService(
            mainActivity,
            ExamplePresentationService.class,
            config.getCastId(castButton.getContext()),
            selectedDevice,
            settings,
            new CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.Callbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onRemoteDisplaySessionStarted(CastRemoteDisplayLocalService service) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceStarted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onRemoteDisplaySessionError(Status errorReason) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceError: " + errorReason.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
    );
}
```

My CastRemoteDisplayLocalService creates the CastPresentation in its createPresentation method:

```
@TargetApi(17)
private void createPresentation(Display display) {
    dismissPresentation();
    mPresentation = new PresentationPlayer(this, display, castHelper, adManager);

    try {
        mPresentation.show();
        //mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to show presentation, display was removed.", ex);
        dismissPresentation();
    }
}
```

And when the user selects a video, the following code is executed in CastPresentation:

```
public void startVideo(VideoData data) {
    FrameLayout videoBase = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cast_video_frame);
    videoBase.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    toggleLogoScreen(false);
    if (player != null) {
        player.stop();
        player.close();
        player = null;
        videoBase.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    player = CvpPlayer.create(PlayerConstants.PlayerType.NEXSTREAM, castHelper.getExampleMainActivity(), videoBase);
    player.setPlayerListener(this);
    player.initPlayer();
}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please file a bug and provide logs: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list